# difference between shape.rectangle and path.rectangle in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I am a newbie to paperjs. I can'get what is the difference between Shape.Rectangle and Path.Rectangle. If path.Rectangle creates a rectangle with path, then what does that mean, since output of both methods is the same

Answer (score 2):

`Path` and `Shape` are different classes, with different drawing methods, but the output is similar.
However, a difference I've noticed is for scaling: `Shape`s modify `strokeWidth`, while `Path`s leave it unchanged

```js
path = new Path.Rectangle([200, 100], [10, 100]);
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.scale(10, 1);

shape = new Shape.Rectangle([200, 220], [10, 100]);
shape.strokeColor = 'red';
shape.scale(10, 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're seeing this difference in scaling is due to the `item.applyMatrix` flag. It should be fairly well explained in these two links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/4EIRSGzcaUI
http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#applymatrix

By default, Path items apply the transformations directly to their segments, hence the stroke appears uniform.

Shape items on the other hand cannot pass on the transformation to their contents, they always store them in the matrix (and `shape.applyMatrix` is always `false`).

But you can have Shape items rendered with a uniform stroke also, using `item.strokeScaling`:

http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#strokescaling